# Character � in PHP 5 to 7 migration. Could be an encoding problem?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, smarty

When migrating a website from php 5 to 7, some special characters like accents are converted to �. Website was built in php 5 using Smarty framework and it use a MariaDB database.

I've tried changing database codification from latin1 to utf8, introduced some lines in .htaccess like defaultCharset=UTF-8,etc. Change headers in all html/xml docs... but I can't find a solution for the problem.

Comment: Did you migrate the database or its use the same? If it's the same look for the connexion, does your new connect to db add a charset?

Comment: Same DB, I'll check, many thanks.

Comment: You mean when you read the DB on php these character appear , or they are there inside the DB when viewing with phpMyAdmin for example?